# Power BI Service Doesn't Save Bookmarks?

Tags: powerbi, bookmarks

We maintain workspaces through Power BI Service for our end-users.  Recently, we had several end-users save bookmarks for their own custom views for a Dashboard we published.  However, the bookmarks our end-users set do not remain saved when they re-open the Dashboard using Power BI Service

I have no idea how to resolve this issue.  Our end-users are upset that they can't save their bookmarks.